# Algorithm to calibrate & normalize readings from multiple temperature sensors

Tags: c++, statistics, normalization

I'm building a custom HVAC controller. Among other things, it will have temperature sensors in multiple locations. The problem is, at any given instant, the sensors all have slightly different opinions about the current air temperature.

For example, right now, I'm getting the following readings (all sensors are in the same spot):

- 75.4F (SHT11)
- 77.0F (HTU21d)
- 77.7F (BME280)
- 76.1F (DS18B20)
- 76.1F (DS18B20)
- 76.5F (DS18B20)
- 75.7F (DS18B20)

Once I've collected a few sets of simultaneous readings with those sensors in various locations (say, inside the freezer, inside the refrigerator, on my desk in an air-conditioned room, and outside in the shade) to see how their individual opinions differ when measuring (more or less) the same ambient air temperatures, I need to somehow come up with an algorithm to normalize their individual readings to some reasonably consistent consensus temperature.

In this case, the "real" temperature is "whatever consensus temperature seems to have the best linear agreement among all the sensors".

**Now, the big question... how do I do this?**

I'll be implementing this using C++ (on an Arduino, but at this point it's purely a "C++ and algorithm" problem, not a hardware problem).

Comment: How that criterium is different from a simple average?

Comment: Measurements are not opinions so measures show a temperature gradient in that spot. Also sensor error must be considered in analysis, for DS18B20 is +/-0.5C. The other relevant questions is what that value will be used for,  display? control? If display then an average could be enough, for control perhaps a "weighted" average based on physical volume of each measured item could be better.

Comment: [Weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

Comment: everyone seems to be saying to take an average, but to my understanding it seems that you want to keep all the data points, but 'normalize' them to agree with each other.  Look into Gaussian smoothing... this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Luis - the error specs quoted for most temperature sensors are almost meaningless unless your use case is, "pick one at random from the assembly line, take a reading, and accept it at face value" (eg, if you're going to stick it in a mass-produced product like a weather station with LCD display and use it without further validation & calibration). In reality, their accuracy is a lot better, as long as you're able to compare 2 or 3 samples from it against a known reference to determine the offset and slope of the error.

Comment: My point was that if 2 measurements differ in the specs error or less there's no big interest on taking the average of them because they are on the error range. +/-0.5C = +/-0.9F which is significant given your example values. Again, the relevant question is what the value will be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me for tooting my own horn. I worked on this problem and related ones in my dissertation, [Unified Prediction and Diagnosis in Engineering Systems by means of Distributed Belief Networks](http://riso.sourceforge.net/docs/dodier-dissertation.pdf). See Chapter 6, especially Section 6.5.

I considered models in which the sensor status (working or malfunctioning in one or more ways) is a variable, in addition to the unknown actual variable being measured, and the known measurement. By reasoning about sensor status, you can get some interesting phenomena as mentioned in Sec. 6.5, e.g. sensors agree, one sensor apparently malfunctions, sensors vote against each other, and all disagree.

The dissertation doesn't contain formulas for the sensor model in Sec. 6.5 but I think I could generate them for you if there is interest. Or, of course, you can derive them too.

Comment: This is definitely what I had in mind, though I'm still working to make sense of it since it's slightly over my head ;-)

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're interested. All the Bayesian network stuff is just a formalization or working out the details of assuming that rational belief is to be represented by probability. This is actually simpler than the usual formulation, since it allows for all sources of uncertainty (uncertainty about hypotheses, parameters, unobserved variables, observed variables, and anything else) on an equal footing. My favorite introduction is "Probability, Frequency, and Reasonable Expectation" by R.T. Cox, American Journal of Physics, 14:1 (1946).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to find a "consensus"

the simplest 2:

1. simple average (sum up all temps and divide by number of sensors) [will srew up, if you have a strong outlier]
2. median (sort and then take the value in the middle)

for more check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Other_median-related_concepts

for your stated "best linear agreement" => this is just the simple average. But i'd recommend the median - in my experience this was usually the better choice, since its a bit more resiliant to outliers.